# Change color font of specific text in Header on Excel using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I try to access header in excel to change text format but Not what I want

```
Sub ChangeHeaderFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your actual sheet name
    Dim keywordSheet As Worksheet
    Set keywordSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' Sheet where the keyword is stored

    ' Retrieve the existing header text
    Dim currentHeaderText As String
    currentHeaderText = ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader

    ' Retrieve the keyword from Sheet2
    Dim keyword As String
    keyword = keywordSheet.Range("A1").Value ' Assuming the keyword is in cell A1 of Sheet2

    ' Define formatting codes
    Dim colorCode As String
    colorCode = "&KFF0000" ' Red color
    Dim boldCode As String
    boldCode = "&B"
    Dim italicCode As String
    italicCode = "&I"
    Dim endFormatCode As String
    endFormatCode = "&K&B&I" ' Reset formatting to default

    ' Construct the header with formatting for the keyword
    Dim modifiedHeaderText As String
    modifiedHeaderText = Replace(currentHeaderText, keyword, colorCode & boldCode & italicCode & keyword & endFormatCode)

    ' Apply the formatted header text
    ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = modifiedHeaderText
End Sub
```

"TEST" is value on

```
keywordSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

My result of this code is DOG***TEST***CAT //"TEST" and "CAT" are red color font.
My expect result is DOG***TEST***CAT //only "TEST" is red color font.

So I want to change color font of specific text in Header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code `&K` is not sufficient to "end" the color, you will need to specify the color code for the black color again.

I formatted some text manually and checked with the debugger: Excel itself puts `&K01+000` - I assume that is using color index and tintAndShade (see official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Workbooks-and-Worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers), but I must admit I didn't fully understand it and they give no example).

However, using `&K000000` (= Hex code for black) does the trick also. So simply change the definition for `endFormatCode` to

```
 endFormatCode = "&K000000&B&I"
```